# Wordpress Rewrite Rules to Create pretty URLs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a page template located in our theme folder at `page-templates/event-page.php` that is able to read the `eventpath` URL parameter, and use it execute some ajax queries.

I created the page Event as a child of some other pages, and assigned it the page template. When I use a URL like this all works as expected:

```
/learn-network/events/event/?eventpath=MyEventSlug
```

I would like to have prettier URL pattern such as

```
/learn-network/events/MyEventSlug
```

I added the following code to my `functions.php` but I keep getting 404 error page:

```
function events_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option('rewrite_rules');
    if(!isset($rules['^learn-network/events/([^/]+)/?$'])){
      global $wp_rewrite;
      $wp_rewrite -> flush_rules();
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'events_flush_rules');

function events_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^learn-network/events/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=learn-network%2Fevents%2Fevent&eventpath=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'events_rewrite_rule');

function events_register_query_var($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'eventpath';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'events_register_query_var');
```

I also tried adding the following code but I don't think it is having any effect at this moment:

```
function events_url_rewrite_templates() {
    if(get_query_var('eventpath') && is_singular()){
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/page-templates/event-page.php';
        });
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'events_url_rewrite_templates');
```

I have been trying for days to get this to work without success.

Anybody can help?

**UPDATE**

The recommendation of saving the Permalinks on the Dashboard worked for me. Thank you!

At the end the only code needed was

```
function events_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^learn-network/events/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=learn-network%2Fevents%2Fevent&eventpath=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'events_rewrite_rule');

function events_register_query_var($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'eventpath';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'events_register_query_var');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to  flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes. as mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/#comment-2038).